# Dynamic sql generation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I need to generate a dynamic sql in below specified format where my table is a parameter i.e, Number of columns is not static

For example, below may be the table schema

```
ID Name
1  asd
2  xyz
```

I need a query which generates the select statement as below

```
select 'ID :' + ID + ',Name :'+Name from table
```

The output from generated above sql will be like this
ID : 1, Name:asd
ID : 2, Name:xyz

If the table has more number of columns, select statement that needs to be changes varies as below

```
select 'ID :' + ID + ',Name :'+Name + ',Col3 :' + Col3 ...from table
```

Could someone help me regarding this

Thanks,
Sree

Comment: basically, you need two cursors, one for table, and the other one for columns, use them together with dynamic-sql, use simple string concatenation regardless of any sql injection concerns

Comment: do you need some code that build the select statement for a giveni table ? And do you need that code in TSQL or in some programming language ?

Comment: this should get you started : SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tablename'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve this using below sql

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'tableName'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ''{''+''' 

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '
    "'+COLUMN_NAME+'":"''' + '+coalesce(CAST('+COLUMN_NAME+' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'''')+''",' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
SET @SQL =  LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL)-1) + '
}'' FROM ' + @TableName

PRINT @SQL
```

Thanks,
Sree

Comment: Then please mark this as the answer to close the question.   Click the checkmark to the upper left.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option which uses a little XML and string manipulation

I should add, NULL values will be excluded.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[Name] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'asd')
,(2,'xyz')

Select stuff(
        replace(
         replace(
          replace(
           replace(
            (Select * from @YourTable for XML RAW)
           ,'<row ',',')
          ,'="',':')
         ,'" ',',')
        ,'"/>','')
       ,1,1,'')
```

Returns

```
(No column name)
ID:1,Name:asd,ID:2,Name:xyz
```

Comment: Interesting solution. How to handle escaped characters like `&amp;`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the information schema views.   They contain all the information you need to generate your dynamic sql.   The rest is just simple SQL and patience.

Comment: "...and patience".  I think all answers should end like this from now on.

Comment: : )  A few jobs back I had a boss who called it SMOP:   Simple Matter Of Programming.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.